# Android App throwing error while fetching the data from WCF Service in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

Wcf Service not fetching the data for android app in Xamarin.forms while its working for Windows Phone.
its throwing following error.

> {System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: A system exception has
>   occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure
>   (Connection refused) --->  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:
>   Connection refused at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect
>   (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000f1]  in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket_2_1.cs:1251
>   at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect  (System.Net.HttpWebRequest
>   request) [0x0019b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:213
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) [0x00043]  in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:818
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel+c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0
>   (IAsyncResult r) [0x0001d]  in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/HttpRequestChannel.cs:215
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel+HttpChannelRequestAsyncResult.WaitEnd
>   () [0x00034]  in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/HttpRequestChannel.cs:494
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.EndRequest
>   (IAsyncResult result) [0x00029]  in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/HttpRequestChannel.cs:349
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.Request
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>   [0x00000]  in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/HttpRequestChannel.cs:72
>
> at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg, TimeSpan timeout) [0x0000b]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:584
>
> at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request 
>   (System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od, Boolean
>   isAsync, System.Object[]& parameters,
>   System.ServiceModel.OperationContext context) [0x00069]  in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:536

Comment: Well the exception says that the connection was refused - so presumably you're either connecting to the wrong host (or port), or on the wrong network.

Comment: could you able to access wcf service via webbrowser?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access via web browser. even its working for window phone but its not working for android phone.

Comment: do you have Internet permissions enabled in your manifest?